# can you develop an algorithm that runs in a given specific time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

ill try to rephrase it: can you find an algorithm of complexity O(x) for an arbitrary complexity O(x)?

Comment: Are you searching for a proof of work algorithm?

Comment: no, I'm asking if it is possible for any given time complexity to create an algorithm that runs in the given time complexity.

Comment: How does this differ from a proof of work algorithm?

Comment: This seems more suitable for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The empty algorithm will be in O(f(x)) for any non-negative f(x).